# Scala sys.process does not seem to block

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm calling Scala's sys.process to execute an AWS file copy from within a spark application.

According to the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder), the ProcessBuilder returned by Scala's sys.process.Process (cmd) should block until the code completes when using `!` or `!!`
However, when I execute the commands below, I see the output in the log that AWS has received the command and then the SparkContext shuts down, without the copy ever being completed.

These are the last three lines of my `main()` function.

```
val cmd = "aws s3 cp s3://bucket1/folder/ s3://bucket2/folder/ --recursive"
val aTemp = sys.process.Process(cmd)
val xCode = aTemp.!
```

I normally exit with, and I thought this might be the problem. However, it happens with or without this as the last line:

```
system.exit(0)
```

I feel like I'm missing something simple, but I... well, I'm missing it. :-)

Anyone know why it isn't waiting for the command to complete before shutting down Spark?

the problem is happening in two environments, both running on Amazon's EC2 instances.

> Spark 1.6 with Scala 2.10
>
> Spark 2.0 with Scala 2.11

Under potential tl;dr,

> I do see in the logs that my aws command was sent but a second later
> spark shuts down: 16/12/09 19:19:13 INFO amazonaws.request: Received
> successful response: 200, AWS Request ID: X 16/12/09 19:19:13 INFO
> spark.SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook